# How to use docker container as a proxy?

Tags: docker, python, mitmproxy

I have the following docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mitmproxy:
    image: johnmccabe/mitmweb
    container_name: mitmproxy
    command: --cadir /ca --wiface 0.0.0.0 
    restart: always
    ports:
        #- "8080:8080"
        - "8081:8081"

  python:
    image: python
    build: ./python-socks-example
    command: python3 /home/project/socks-example.py
    volumes:
      - ./python-socks-example:/home/project/
    depends_on:
       - mitmproxy
    container_name: python
    restart: always
```

I want my python HTTP requests to go through mitmproxy on the other container. Here's the python code:

```
import requests
import time

while(True):
    time.sleep(5)
    print("gonna connect")
    resp = requests.get('http://google.com', 
                    proxies=dict(http='socks5://user:pass@server.com:8080',
                                 https='socks5://user:pass@server.com:8080'))
    print(resp)
    print("done")
    time.sleep(2)
```

How can I wire the network of `python` to go through `mitmproxy` container?

Answer (score 0):

In your python code, you'll need to reference the other service.

The proxy URL should be updated to have the right hostname. Which is to say replacing `server.com` with the name of of the *service* offering whatever you're trying to connect to.

In this case, you'd replace `server.com` with `mitmproxy`.

Meaning your python code would look as such:

```
import requests
import time

while(True):
    time.sleep(5)
    print("gonna connect")
    resp = requests.get('http://google.com', 
                    proxies=dict(http='socks5://user:pass@mitmproxy:8080',
                                 https='socks5://user:pass@mitmproxy:8080'))
    print(resp)
    print("done")
    time.sleep(2)
```